# in python 3.6.i want to use sklearn tree to classify but appear ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'NC',

Tags: python, scikit-learn

This is my code

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
from sklearn import tree
os.chdir('C:/Users/Shinelon/Desktop/ch13')
w=pd.read_table('cup98lrn.txt',sep=',',low_memory=False)
w1=(w.loc[:,['AGE','AVGGIFT','CARDGIFT','CARDPM12','CARDPROM','CLUSTER2','DOMAIN','GENDER','GEOCODE2','HIT',
           'HOMEOWNR','HPHONE_D','INCOME','LASTGIFT','MAXRAMNT',
           'MDMAUD_F','MDMAUD_R','MINRAMNT','NGIFTALL','NUMPRM12',
           'RAMNTALL',
           'RFA_2A','RFA_2F','STATE','TIMELAG','TARGET_B']]).dropna(how='any')
x=w1.loc[:,['AGE','AVGGIFT','CARDGIFT','CARDPM12','CARDPROM','CLUSTER2','DOMAIN','GENDER','GEOCODE2','HIT',
           'HOMEOWNR','HPHONE_D','INCOME','LASTGIFT','MAXRAMNT',
           'MDMAUD_F','MDMAUD_R','MINRAMNT','NGIFTALL','NUMPRM12',
           'RAMNTALL',
           'RFA_2A','RFA_2F','STATE','TIMELAG']]
y=w1.loc[:,['TARGET_B']]
clf=tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(min_samples_split=1000,min_samples_leaf=400,max_depth=10)
print(w1.head())
clf=clf.fit(x,y)
```

but appear the question I can't understand .because i use sklearn.tree before .D:\python3.6\python.exe C:/Users/Shinelon/Desktop/ch13/.idea/13.4.py

```
     AGE    AVGGIFT  CARDGIFT  CARDPM12  CARDPROM  CLUSTER2 DOMAIN GENDER  \
1   46.0  15.666667         1         6        12       1.0     S1      M   
3   70.0   6.812500         7         6        27      41.0     R2      F   
4   78.0   6.864865         8        10        43      26.0     S2      F   
6   38.0   7.642857         8         4        26      53.0     T2      F   
11  75.0  12.500000         2         6         8      23.0     S2      M   

   GEOCODE2  HIT    ...    MDMAUD_R  MINRAMNT  NGIFTALL  NUMPRM12  RAMNTALL  \
1         A   16    ...           X      10.0         3        13      47.0   
3         C    2    ...           X       2.0        16        14     109.0   
4         A   60    ...           X       3.0        37        25     254.0   
6         D    0    ...           X       3.0        14         9     107.0   
11        B    3    ...           X      10.0         2        12      25.0   

   RFA_2A RFA_2F  STATE  TIMELAG  TARGET_B  
1       G      2     CA     18.0         0  
3       E      4     CA      9.0         0  
4       F      2     FL     14.0         0  
6       E      1     IN      4.0         0  
11      F      2     IN      3.0         0
```

this is print(w1) result

Comment: Well the error is clear you have a string 'NC' which presumably stands for not classified so you need to replace this with some meaningful numeric value or drop them

Comment: i.m sorry ,i from china .the English is not good .but i know number can be feature in DecisionTreeClassifier.why  replace this with some meaningful numeric value or drop them

Comment: because the classifying models understand numeric values not strings, you'd need to convert a string/encode it so it can apply it's algorithm, for instance why would a model understand what 'cat' and 'dog' were? However it does understand what `1` and `0` are.

Comment: thinks you help .i think i can solve this problem.

Comment: Basically you need to replace 'NC' with `np.NaN` or remove/replace them. Note that changes to data will affect your model

Comment: All the columns in your data which have string values (like 'DOMAIN','GENDER','GEOCODE2' etc..) will throw the above error. You need to transform them to numeric values. Like for gender you can do M=0, F=1 etc. Search about preprocessing the features and converting categorical features to numeric on internet